# Can I link table headers to table data in html?

Tags: html, sql

I have several table columns named in table headers. The data comes from python file.

```
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ecp_hs_app/Datatable/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css' %}">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ecp_hs_app/Datatable/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css' %}">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'ecp_hs_app/Datatable/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<thead class = "thead-dark">
    <tr style="column-fill: balance">
                   <th id ="Pat Number">Patient Number</th>
                   <th>Enrolled Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
        {% for pat, missed, report in site_ses %} 
               <tr>
                   <td headers = "Pat Number" class="a" align="center">{{ pat.patientnum }}</a></td> 
                   <td class="a" align="center"> {{pat.startdate}}</td>
               </tr>...
```

Can I connect the headers to the data so the order of the table data is irrelevant? 
I think this will help me reference the html table headers in my sql query in the python file.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you asking how to sort a table in the browser (using JavaScript, by clicking on a table header)?

Comment: You can query metadata of the table to collect all column names and put them on the html.